# Understanding Annotation Processing in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Can someone describe the use of **annotation processing**?
My last attempt to understand annotations was unsuccessful.

Previously I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685795/help-me-understanding-annotation-in-java) but couldn't get a satisfactory answer.
I went through many online tutorials but most of them are about annotations used for:

1. Documentation
2. Annotations used by the compiler (`@Deprecated`, `@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings`)
3. Annotation processing (`@Target` and `@Retention`)

Please someone explain me **Annotation Processing** by directing me to appropriate tutorial.

To be very precise I want to know more about the following
*Meta-Annotations* (Java Annotation Types):

- Target
- Retention
- Documented
- Inherited

I already went through many tutorials like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) but couldn't get much information on Annotation Processing.

Comment: annotation processing is very vague. what specifically do you want information about? runtime processing? compile-time processing? annotations specific to Hibernate?

Comment: @Mat ....can you please direct me to the link which can give me information regarding @Test and @Retention types annotation used in context of Hibernate

Comment: those are not Hibernate annotations. They're core java. tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html

Comment: for instance, using Class.getAnnotations() -  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations()

Comment: thanks Stephen for given example of reflection.. :) now can you plz give an example of annotation too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotations asked about are annotations used for annotating Annotations. Their specific purposes are:

- `Target`: Specifies where you can use the annotation. E.g. `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)` means the Annotation can only be used on methods.
- `Retention`: Specifies where/when the annotation is available. `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` means it is available at runtime using reflection. Other values make it only in the class files orat compile time (the options mentioned first include the later options)
- `Documented` An annotation with this annotation will apear in javadoc
- `Inherited` makes subclasses inherit the annoteted annotation from their superclasses

For all four the javadoc is quite helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

@Anupam Gupta - I think your problem is that you do not have a good enough understanding of basic / core Java to be able to understand how annotations and annotation processing really work.  For instance, the fact that you don't understand what "reflectively at runtime" means suggests that you are not familiar with Java reflection, and that's an important part of core Java.

Annotation *processing* is an advanced topic, and is really beyond the scope of the Java tutorial streams.

---

For what it is worth, the Annotation documentation is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html), [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#processing), and you maybe can get more clues by reading the messages in the Oracle [annotations forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=931).

Comment: Thanks Stephen ...u are right my core java understanding is at initial stage and i am still at learning phase but i believe you all must have passed through this learning phase ... I just read and learned about reflection ..now can you please help me with the annotation ... if there is no tutorial then guide me about how to get knowledge about annotation ..

Comment: @Anupam Gupta - I don't think I can explain this to you.  Basically, you will need to read the annotation documentation for yourself.  But to be honest, I think you are wasting your time.