# How should I write my own custom Annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations

Let say I want to check condition[let say boundary values] on some of the method arguments.Instead of writing "if" condition to check [boundary condition] on every method, I want to annotate argument only. Let me know the Steps to understand it. Working code will be awesome.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/. Annotations don't do anything. They just add metadata to the code. You would need a tool, at runtime, to read those annotations and do something with them.

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27781761/1697099 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5686231/1697099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into method interception. What you are wanting is an interceptor that can validate method arguments on invocation. I like the AOP Alliance interfaces for this, they work pretty well. It also integrates with Guice natively and I think Spring has support for it as well.

Steps:

1. Define an annotation
2. Create an interceptor to process the annotation
3. Bind the interceptor (manually or using some framework)